# Mini shopping cart for a site on MODX

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

Please help in improving the code. I would like to hear comments on syntax and an approach to development. This is my first experience in writing a simple application for the site.

```
window.onload = function() {

    /* инициализация таблицы-прайса
    Вначале проверяем наличие таблицы-прайса на странице.
    Класс таблицы с прайсом должен быть => table-price.
    Подразумевается такая структура колонок таблицы прайса:
        | Артикул | Наименование | Стоимость |

    */

    // проверяем наличие прайса на странице
    function priceOnPage(){
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('table') !== undefined) {
            var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

            for (var i=0, tablesLength = tables.length; i<tablesLength; i++) {
                if (tables[i].classList.contains('table-price')) {
                    return tables[i];
                };
            };
        };
    };

    // если прайса нет на странице, то останавливаем весь скрипт
    if (priceOnPage() === undefined) {
        return false;
    };

    // задаем использумые классы элементов таблицы
    var option = ['item-id', 'item-title', 'item-price'];

    // берем tr - строка с данными
    var table = priceOnPage();
    var itemBox = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i=1, itemRowTotal = itemBox.length; i<itemRowTotal; i++) {

        // добавляем ячейку td для кнопки
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        itemBox[i].appendChild(td); 

        var item = itemBox[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

        // добавляем классы ячейкам td
        for (var j=0, itemCellTotal = item.length; j<itemCellTotal; j++) {

            // добавляем кнопку "Добавить" в каждую строку tr
            if (j == item.length-1) {
                item[j].innerHTML = '<a class="add_item">Добавить в корзину</a>';
                continue;
            }

            item[j].setAttribute('class', option[j]);
        };
    };

    /* Набор стандартных кроссбраузерных функций */

    // кроссбраузерная установка обработчиков
    function addEvent(el, type, handler) {
        if (el.addEventListener) {
            /* Chrome, Mozilla, Opera, Safari */
            el.addEventListener(type, handler);
        } else {
            /* IE */
            elem.attachEvent('on' +type, function() {
                handler.call(elem);
            });
        };
        return false;
    };

    // получение/запись данных в LocalStorage
    function getCartData(item) {
        if (item) {
            // если передаются даныне, то записываем...
            localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(item));
            return false;
        } else {
            // ... либо получаем
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        };  
    };

    // проверка объета на пустоту
    function isEmpty(obj) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var key in obj) {
            count++;
        };

        if (count>0) {
            return false;
        };
        return true;
    };

    /* Основной функционал */

    // если LS не пуст, то показываем мини-корзину и формируем таблицу в модальном окне
    if (!isEmpty(getCartData())) {
        miniOpenCart();
        openCart();
    };

    // Добавляем товар в корзину
    function addToCart(e){
        this.disabled = true; // блокируем кнопку на время операции с корзиной
        var cartData = getCartData() || {}; // получаем данные корзины или создаём новый объект, если данных еще нет
        var parentBox = this.parentNode.parentNode; // родительский элемент кнопки "Добавить в корзину"
        var itemId = parentBox.getAttribute('data-id'); // ID товара
        var itemTitle = parentBox.querySelector('.item-title').innerHTML; // название товара
        var itemPrice = parentBox.querySelector('.item-price').innerHTML; // стоимость товара

        if (cartData.hasOwnProperty(itemId)){ // если такой товар уже в корзине, то добавляем +1 к его количеству
            cartData[itemId][2] += 1;
        } else { // если товара в корзине еще нет, то добавляем в объект
            cartData[itemId] = [itemTitle, itemPrice, 1];
        };

        if (!getCartData(cartData)){ // Обновляем данные в LocalStorage
            this.disabled = false; // разблокируем кнопку после обновления LS
        };

        miniOpenCart(); // показываем корзину
        openCart();
        return false;
    };

    // Удаляем товар из корзины
    function deleteItem() {
        var cartData = getCartData();
        var id = this.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id');
        delete cartData[id];
        getCartData(cartData);
        openCart();

        // если пусто, то удаляем виджет корзины и модальное окно
        if (isEmpty(cartData)) {
            var miniCart = document.getElementById('mini_cart');
            miniCart.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            miniCart.classList.remove('fadeIn');

            var cartModal = document.getElementById('cartModal');
            cartModal.classList.remove('in');
        };
    };

    // Добавляем обработчик на кнопки
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('add_item');
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        addEvent(items[i], 'click', addToCart);
    };

    // мини карта корзины
    function miniOpenCart() {
        var items = getCartData();
        var count = 0;

        for (var key in items) {
            count++;
        };

        var miniCart = document.getElementById('mini_cart');
        miniCart.classList.add('animated');
        miniCart.classList.add('fadeIn');
        miniCart.style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count;
    };

    // формируем и показываем корзину
    function openCart() {
        var data = getCartData();

        // формируем корзину в модальном окне
        var output = '<table class="table"><tr><td>Наименование</td><td>Цена</td><td>Кол-во</td><td></td></tr><tr>';

        for (var key in data) {
            output += '<tr data-id="' + key + '">';

            for (var i=0; i<data[key].length; i++) {
                output += '<td>' + data[key][i] + '</td>';
            };

            output += '<td><a class="delete_item">Удалить</a></td>';
            output += '</tr>';
        };

        output += '</table>';

        var cart = document.getElementById('cart-in-modal');
        cart.innerHTML = output;

        //  добавялем кнопку "Удалить"
        var deleteItems = cart.getElementsByClassName('delete_item');

        for (var i=0; i<deleteItems.length; i++) {
            addEvent(deleteItems[i], 'click', deleteItem);
        };

        // формируем шаблон report для eForm
        var report = '<table><tr><td>Наименование</td><td>Цена</td><td>Кол-во</td></tr><tr>';

        for (var key in data) {
            report += '<tr>';

            for (var i=0; i<data[key].length; i++) {
                report += '<td>' +data[key][i]+ '</td>';
            };

            report += '</tr>';
        };

        var input = document.getElementById('input-cart-modal');
        input.value = report;
    };

    /* Модальное окно */
    (function() {
        var temp = $('#myModal_form').html();
        $("body").on("submit", "#cart_modal", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
            var m_action=$(this).attr('action');
            var m_data=$(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: m_method,
                url: m_action,
                data: m_data,
                resetForm: 'true',
                success: function(result){
                    var response = $(result).find('#myModal_form').html();
                    $('#myModal_form').html(response);
                    localStorage.clear();

                    // удаляем мини-корзину
                    if (isEmpty(getCartData())) {
                        var miniCart = document.getElementById('mini_cart');
                        miniCart.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    };

                    // скрываем модальное окно
                    $('#myModal_form').html(temp);
                    var cartModal = document.getElementById('cartModal');
                    cartModal.classList.remove('in');

                },
                error: function(err) {
                    var response = $(result).find('#myModal_form').html();
                    $('#myModal_form').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }());
}
```

Comment: would you please translate the comments to English.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Coments**

Don't use Russian (or any other langugage except English) in comments. Also, it's a good idea to not comment your code much in obvious cases, e.g.

```
// Удаляем товар из корзины
function deleteItem() {
```

2. **priceOnPage**

Why not use `getElementById`? It can be slow to search throw all tables in DOM. Also, you're searching for it twice.

3. **isEmpty**

You can just use something way more simpler:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for (var _ in obj) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

4. **Don't mix code and functions**

Just split them: all functions first, then code.

5. **`;` after block statements maybe omitted**

---

I'll try to add more later.